# Обрезать оригинальное название фото в конце уникального названия PHP

Tags: php, fileupload

Доброй ночи.

Вопрос в следующем.

Код генерирует уникальные имена для фотографий, но после того как он это делает, в конце все равно пишет оригинальное название фото при загрузке.

**Грузим файл с именем:**   Photo.jpg

**На выходе получаем:**  alefje9974348iuefbszzPhoto.jpg

А задача чтобы в названии фотографий оставались только уникально сгенерированные символы по типу: alefje9974348iuefbszz.jpg

Не могу понять где убрать оригинальное имя, подскажите плиз.

```
  
 $data = $_POST;
 $photo = $_FILES;
    
    
    if(isset($data['submit']))       { 
     

      /* Папка с фото */
      

           $uploads_dir = '../Images';
      
       
foreach ($photo["file"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
  
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
      
       $tmp_name = $photo["file"]["tmp_name"][$key];
      
        $extension = $photo["file"]["type"][$key];
      
      
      /* Токен*/

      
          $token = random_bytes(7);
      
      
      /* Новое имя */
      
       
              $name =  bin2hex(microtime() . $token) . ($photo["file"]["name"][$key]);
      
      
      
      /* Загружаем  */
      
           
                    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
      
     
    
}

      
      
      
   
 echo'<pre>';
         print_r($name);
       echo'</pre>';
   
   
      
      
      print_r($data);
      
       echo'<pre>';
         print_r($photo);
       echo'</pre>';
  
      
      
      
  } 
}
```

Comment: очевидно, в той строке, где формируете `$name`.  там у вас даже комментарий подписан, что эта строка создает новое имя. Неужели оттуда не ясно, каким образом туда попадает имя старого файла?

Comment: @teran   Убирали из формирования нового имени ["name"] тогда он выкидывает разрешение фотографии. Нужно отдельной переменной сделать $extension и включить его в формирование нового имени???

Comment: формально у вас уже есть переменная extension, которая указывает на mime-тип файла и не далее не используется. Да. возьмите из name расширение, и используйте при формировании нового имени. В целом, наверное не помешало бы проверить, какие типы файлов разрешено загружать, а то так и пхп скрипт можно загрузить.

Comment: @teran    Сейчас сделала расширение в конце $extension , но он установил не просто .jpeg а взял из массива название   image/jpeg   что соответственно не дало правильного расширения фотографий. Фото теперь выглядят вот так: sfhskln.image/jpeg

Comment: так я вам об этом и написал, что надо взять из name, т..к текущее там mime-тип

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/* Получаем название */

      $original_name = $photo["file"]["name"][$key];


/* Получаем расширение */


              $extension = pathinfo($original_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

В переменной `$name` подставляем в конец строки конкатенацией `$extension`, убираем `["name"]` и все полетит.